# NodeJS + Hapi + CSS Trouble

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, hapi.js

I am making a small webhost in Node js using hapi 
this is for practice as I'm not super familiar with node but I'm learning the best I can.

My current issue is, I am trying to get a css file from an include directory. 
using Hapi my app.js looks a little like this:

```
var Path = require("path");
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var HandleBars = require('handlebars');
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.views({
    engines: {
        html: HandleBars
    },
    path: './views'
});

server.connection({
    port: 5000,
    host: "localhost"
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        reply.view('index.html');
    }
});

server.route({
    method: '*',
    path: '/{p*}',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        reply.view('404.html').code(404);
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/images/{param*}',
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: 'public/images'
        }
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{file}.css',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file("/includes/css/"+request.params.file+".css");
    }
});

server.start(function(err) {
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

and my index.html looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="" alt="First slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Welcome to Beta</h1>
                        <p>Welcome to our site beta, as you will notice a lot of functionality is still being developed. Please be patient!</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read Latest Log</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/NewBG.png" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>OOHHH the SPOOKS</h1>
                        <p>Watch out for the Spooks!</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/buttonindie.png" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Proud Supporter of Indie</h1>
                        <p>Welcome to our Indie Game page for State of Grey! a new ariel view pixel horror game based in the VX Ace Game engine. Click our About tab and learn about the team!</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Example row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>{{title1}}</h2>
                <p>{{content}}</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="{{detailsLink1}}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
                </p>
            </div>


     <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>{{title2}}</h2>
            <p>{{content}}</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="{{detailsLink2}}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>{{title3}}</h2>
            <p>{{content}}</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="{{detailsLink3}}" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--#include virtual="/web/includes/footer.html"-->


</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

When I run my host through heroku locally I can't seem to find main.css when it's called by `/` when I console log the path it seems to be pointing perfectly where I need it to go. However it still shows up as 404 not found. Could anyone point me in a solid direction? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Won't "main.css" match the top-level `/` path?

Comment: It's suppose to be whenever `/` calls a file.css it should send back the path with the css file but maybe I didn't do that right.

Comment: Well I'm no expert with that framework but it looks like it stops at the first route that matches the path. I would try to determine whether that plain "/" matches anything. It's pretty common for routing mechanisms like that to split your paths into "/app/..." and "/statics/..." for this very reason.

Comment: Yep. I was sending it to the wrong location, I forgot to specify views in my pathing, which is where include was, fixed now. thanks for the assist to my overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you provide the route is important. You must go from the most specific to the most generic. As *@Pointy* suggest, your request to get the `/main.css` is hidden by the 404 route

```
{path: '/{p*}',
handler: function(request, reply) {
    reply.view('404.html').code(404);
```

You'll find here more detail about serving static file in the [api documentation](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files#file-handler-options)